# Bootstrap-DatePicker not triggering on glyphicon?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I'm using Eternicode's Bootstrap-Datepicker in an MVC Form. I'm trying to get the pop-up calendar to trigger on the glyphicon. Currently it will trigger the calendar when I click on the input field but not the glyphicon. I do get the hand cursor when I mouse over the glyphicon, just no trigger. When I look at the F12 dev tools on the page I don't see any errors.

I am using the built in MVC bundling and have the scripts rendering at the bottom of the page.

Look at the documents it seems as though all I have to do is add the "date" class to the "input-group" class. I've got that set as well but doesn't seem to work.

View:

```
@model CPPCustomerCall.ViewModels.CustomerCallVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section Scripts {
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Views/CallCreate.js")"></script>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<div class="container">

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Customer Call</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "autofocus" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CallMessage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.CallMessage, new { cols = 50, @rows = 5, @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CallMessage, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CallDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="input-group date">
                        <input id="CallDate" name="CallDate" class="form-control" type="text" />
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create Call" class="btn btn-success" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

</div>

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - CPP Customer Call</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

</head>
<body data-ng-app="cppApp">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("CPP Customer Call", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Calls", "Index", "CustomerCalls")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Grid", "Index", "Grid")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/tools")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

CallCreate.js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Datepicker
    $('#CallDate').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        $('#CallDate').datepicker('hide');
    });   
});
```

Bundle.config

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/tools").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryinputmask").Include(
                "~/Scripts/digitalbush.maskedinput.js"));

    // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
    // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
              "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
              "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
              "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
              "~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css",
              "~/Content/site.css"));
}
```

Comment: It seems that you are not loading `jquery`...In your view, above `jqueryval` add this line `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/tools")`

Comment: Thanks for looking and the suggestion, however, the tools bundle is on the _Layout.cshtml at the bottom. That should put it on all pages. Just to confirm I ran the page and opened up the DevTools (F12) in Chrome and I can see jQuery v1.10.2 referenced first and then bootstrap.js and then bootstrap-datepicker.js and then CallCreate.js, etc. I would think bootstrap.js would need to be loaded before bootstrap-datepicker.js but I might switch the order of those to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I switched the order that bootstrap.js and bootstrap-datepicker were loaded but that didn't affect anything. I had a feeling it wouldn't but I'm kind of grasping at straws to figure out the issue.

Comment: Yes but, remove it from _Layout.cshtml or place that instruction above @RenderBody

Comment: Ok, gave that a try but it didn't work. I have to have the jQuery for Bootstrap to work. So removing it from the layout page and putting jQuery in the specific View ended up causing Bootstrap to not work. I had to put it back in the layout page. It's just weird that I get the cursor on the glyphicon and the trigger works on the input....just no trigger on the glyphicon. I also have this in another small site I'm trying to create and I get the same issue there. I wonder if it has to to with the version of jQuery or something. I think DatePicker is verified up to 1.07 and I'm using 1.10.